# R flexdashboard Error in disabling the submit button even if there is no radio button option is selected or when any option is selected

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard, shinyjs

In my flexdashboard code, what I am trying to do is:

- initially, no radio button is selected, and there are two options only
- option (radio button) one is to upload the data, option two is to connect to MySQL server for retrieving the data

code looks like this:

````
```{r setup, include = FALSE}

library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(bslib)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(htmltools)
library(fontawesome)
library(shinyjs)
library(RMySQL)
library(shinyWidgets)

useShinyjs()

```

Home 
=====================================

Sidebar {.sidebar data-width=350}
-------------------------------------

```{r}

prettyRadioButtons(
        inputId = "dataChoice",
        label = "Select one:",
        icon = icon("check"),
        choices = c("Upload File", "Data from Database"),
        animation = "tada",
        inline = TRUE,
        status = "default",
        selected = F
      )


tags$div(id = "one", actionButton("submitbtn1", "Submit"))

observeEvent(input$dataChoice, {
  ifelse(is.null(input$dataChoice), shinyjs::disable(id = "one"),
                  ifelse(input$dataChoice=='Upload File',
                         shinyjs::enable(id = "one"),
                         shinyjs::disable(id = "one"))
  )}
})

```
````

I want to **disable** the `submit` button when there is no radio button selected or option `Data from Database` is selected. But submit button should be **enabled** when radio button option `Upload File` is selected.

Somehow the code above is not working and the moment I click on first option, error appears and app stops abruptly. What am I doing wrong here?

I used the conditionalPanel() from below reply, but now another issue is:

```
conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.dataChoice == 'Upload File'",  {
  tags$hr(),
  checkboxInput('header', 'Your Data has Header?', TRUE),
  renderText(ifelse(input$header=='TRUE', "Headers present.", "No headers present.")),
  tags$br(),
  prettyRadioButtons(
          inputId = "separator",
          label = "Type:",
          icon = icon("check"),
          choices = c(Comma=',', Semicolon=';'),
          inline = TRUE,
          status = "default"
        ),
            
  .....
  
  actionButton("submit", "Submit")

     }
  )
```

Only `actionButton()` is working, while other items are not shown. Not sure if `conditionalPanel()` has such options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditionalPanel (https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/conditionalpanel)

Notice the condition syntax. Specifically notice input.dataChoice instead of input$dataChoice

```
prettyRadioButtons(
  inputId = "dataChoice",
  label = "Select one:",
  icon = icon("check"),
  choices = c("Upload File", "Data from Database"),
  animation = "tada",
  inline = TRUE,
  status = "default",
  selected = F
)

conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.dataChoice == 'Upload File'", 
  actionButton("submitbtn1", "Submit")
)
```

Comment: but if i want to use another prettyradioButtons, checkbox and File Input before submit button inside conditionalPanel(), it doest work and only submit button is shown when I select Upload File option in the above code.. why??

Comment: I see you have an extra bracket "{" at the end of the first line ...      condition = "input.dataChoice == 'Upload File'",  {
 Get rid of it, and the corresponding "}" at the end of your code. Tell me if that works.